# Can't Return ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm having problems with a project of mine. It's a virtual database for films. I have two classes, MovieEntry (small, for individual entries) and MovieDatabase (large, and the code below.) I'm getting an error returning my ArrayLists such as in searchYear. It says incompatible types. Why can I not return an ArrayList?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class MovieDatabase
{
   private ArrayList<MovieEntry> Database = new ArrayList<MovieEntry>();
   public MovieDatabase(){
       ArrayList<MovieDatabase> Database = new ArrayList<MovieDatabase>(0);
    }

   public int countTitles() throws IOException{
       Scanner fileScan;
       fileScan = new Scanner (new File("movies.txt"));
       int count = 0;
       String movieCount;
       while(fileScan.hasNext()){
           movieCount = fileScan.nextLine();
           count++;
        }
       return count;
    }

   public void addMovie(MovieEntry m){
       Database.add(m);
    }

   public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchTitle(String substring){
       for (MovieEntry title : Database)
          System.out.println(title);
          return null;
    }

   public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchGenre(String substring){
       for (MovieEntry genre : Database)
          System.out.println(genre);
          return null;
    }

   public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchDirector (String str){
       for (MovieEntry director : Database)
          System.out.println(director);
          return null;
    }

   public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchYear (int yr){
       ArrayList <String> yearMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
       for (MovieEntry m : Database)
       m.getYear(yr);
        if(yearMatches.contains(yr) == false){
           String sYr = Integer.toString(yr);
           yearMatches.add(sYr);
        }
       return yearMatches;
    }

   public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchYear(int from, int to){
       ArrayList <String> Matches = new ArrayList<String>();
       for(MovieEntry year : Database);
          Matches.add();
       return Matches;
    }

   public void readMovieData(String movies){
       String info;
       try{
           Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File(movies));
           Scanner lineReader;

           while(fileReader.hasNext()){
               info = fileReader.nextLine();

               lineReader = new Scanner(info);
               lineReader.useDelimiter(":");

               String title = lineReader.next();
               String director = lineReader.next();
               String genre = lineReader.next();
               int year = lineReader.nextInt();
            }

        }catch(FileNotFoundException error){
            System.out.println("File not found.");

        }catch(IOException error){
            System.out.println("Oops! Something went wrong.");
        }
    }

   public int countGenres(){
    ArrayList <String> gList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(MovieEntry m : Database){
      String g = m.getGenre(g);
      if(gList.contains(g) == false){
        gList.add(g);
      }
      return gList.size();
    }
    }

    public int countDirectors(){
     ArrayList <String> dList = new ArrayList<String>();
     for(MovieEntry m : Database){
        String d = m.getDirector(d);
        if(dList.contains(d) == false){
            dList.add(d);
        }
        return dList.size();
     }

     }

    public String listGenres(){
        ArrayList <String> genreList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }




}
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Please indent your code properly - it's very misleading at the moment. (Personally I'd also suggest *always* using open/close braces for blocks, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 4):

You are declaring your functions to return `ArrayList<MovieEntry>` and the variable you are returning is declared to be an `ArrayList<String>`. You need to change one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning `ArrayList <String>` when a `ArrayList<MovieEntry>` is expected.
ps : even if your code compiles, it seems there are lot of mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

```
public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchYear (int yr){
    ArrayList <String> yearMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (MovieEntry m : Database)
        m.getYear(yr);
    if(yearMatches.contains(yr) == false){
        String sYr = Integer.toString(yr);
        yearMatches.add(sYr);
    }
    return yearMatches;
}
```

The return value supposed to be a list of `MovieEntry` objects, not `String` objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchYear (int yr){
   ArrayList <String> yearMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
   // ...
   return yearMatches;
}
```

Your method signature says you're returning an `ArrayList<MovieEntry>` but you're actually returning an `ArrayList<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this code in detail, just as one example:

```
public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchYear (int yr){
    ArrayList <String> yearMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (MovieEntry m : Database)
    m.getYear(yr);
     if(yearMatches.contains(yr) == false){
        String sYr = Integer.toString(yr);
        yearMatches.add(sYr);
     }
    return yearMatches;
}
```

Firstly, let's fix the indentation, and add braces for clarity:

```
public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchYear (int yr){
    ArrayList <String> yearMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (MovieEntry m : Database) {
        m.getYear(yr);
    }
    if(yearMatches.contains(yr) == false){
       String sYr = Integer.toString(yr);
       yearMatches.add(sYr);
    }
    return yearMatches;
}
```

So, this raises questions:

- Why are you calling `m.getYear(yr)` and completely ignoring the result?
- Why are you asking whether an `ArrayList<String>` contains an `int`? How could it?
- Why are you expecting to be able to return an `ArrayList<String>` as an `ArrayList<MovieEntry>`? You're only adding the string value of the year to `yearMatches` - that's not a `MovieEntry`!

The last part is the reason for the *compile-time* error... but the rest of the code is simply broken. I suspect you want:

```
public List<MovieEntry> searchYear(int year) {
    List<MovieEntry> yearMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (MovieEntry m : Database) {
        if (m.getYear() == year) {
            yearMatches.add(m);
        }
    }
    return yearMatches;
}
```

Comment: you forgot `for(MovieEntry year : Database);`. Very puzzling

Comment: @UmNyobe: That's in a different method. I was only looking at this specific method.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList <String> yearMatches
```

should be

`ArrayList<MovieEntry> yearMatches` because your method signature is

```
ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchYear (int yr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the return type of yearMatches in searchYear

Answer (score 0):

The method specifies that you are going to return a ArrayList, but you try to return a ArrayList.

Change ArrayList to ArrayList and it should work.  Else you have to construct MovieEntry objects to put in your list.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<MovieEntry>` is incompatible with `ArrayList <String>`. Just don't type the return (but I do not think is the right)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess that the error is in your `searchYear` methods. You have the return type be `ArrayList<MovieEntry>`, however, you are returning an `ArrayList<String>`, hence the error.